# Service account impersonating user account on Google Drive from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am developing servlet application on Google App Engine which in response to a POST request should create file in a Google Drive. I want use service account with private key which upload file behalf on real user.

Is it possible? 
Is there any solution avoiding real user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. The Drive docs show you how to use delegation of authority (2 step oauth2) for google apps domain users.
You dont say, but seems like you want the file added to the user's drive. If not, you could use your own drive or a service account drive (3step oauth2 server flow) and share with the user,that has more quota/rate limit issues but doesnt require user permissions other than knowing their email (with appengine user service and google auth option).

Comment: Could you give me more specific details? While using service account how to share file with the user? Another question - is there any way to access service account drive from GUI or some example in Java?

Comment: The official docs show how to change sharing permissions. If you cant get it to work post the code you tried. Also, you cant see the service account with the drive gui.

Comment: I have a problem with accessing private key file in App Engine. I have added reference in appengine-web.xml: `<resource-files><include path="/res" /></resource-files>`. I'm trying to get path to the file located in /res/filename.p12. Code: `File credFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/res/filename.p12").toURI());` And then invokes credential builder. Trying that I receive NullPointerException.

Comment: create a new question.